# profile switching in vim?

Tags: vim

I plan to use Vim for two types of developement: Python and Javascript
I have a different set of plugins for each of these.
I wonder if those plugins are in conflict to each other.
and whether there's a mechanizm that "switch the development profile" .

Thanks

Comment: auto load plugins based on file type

Comment: ?? ftplugins are based on filetype. autoload plugins are not made to unload and reload automatically when switching buffer. I don't see how they could help ; except to write multi-ft aware plugins through some kind of polymorphism (which I use in my refactoring suite). This is tricky, and not exactly helping the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -u switch to load non-default .vimrc file (-U for .gvimrc), and there you may load specific plugins. You may create shortcuts or aliases to that command, and have different profiles that way.

Maybe it's not live switching, but that's the simplest approach.

Answer (score 3):

If the plugins you use are correctly written (buffer local settings, commands, abbreviations, and mappings) everything should be fine. Usually this is done through ftplugins, and not really plugins.

If you see misbehaviours, you'll have to search which plugin(s) are incorrectly written and then contact their maintainers to fix them.